# Why does object.getClass().getClasses() return empty arrays?

Tags: java, reflection

Out of curiosity I was trying to print the `static final int SIZE` field from any classes that have it. To get "any classes that have it" I just tried to get *all* classes. But I noticed that it always returns a length 0 array.

The doc says

> This method returns an array of length 0 if this Class object has no public member classes or interfaces. This method also returns an array of length 0 if this Class object represents a primitive type, an array class, or void

But Object is not listed as a primitive. Is Object somehow considered void then?

So, how do I
- Get an array of all classes?
and
- Why does this not work for Object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `getClasses()` method returns an array of all *inner* classes (classes that are declared inside the body) of the class object this method is called on. For most classes, this will always be zero. It is never the union of *all* classes available. 
Take a look at class loaders - in Java there is no method that simply yields all available classes. You need to use a specific class loader that provides this information.